# Random Number with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a script to pick random number between two numbers . but it picks same number sometimes. i donot want to repeat same number until array is finished .

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    abc();
    test = array();

    function abc() {
        res = randomXToY(1, 10, 0);

        $('#img' + res).fadeTo(1200, 1);
        //$(this).addClass('activeImg');
        //});
        setTimeout(function () {
            removeClassImg(res)
        }, 3000);
    }

    function removeClassImg(res) {
        $('#img' + res).fadeTo(1200, 0.1);
        //$('#img' + res).removeClass('activeImg');
        abc();
    }

    function randomXToY(minVal, maxVal, floatVal) {
        var randVal = minVal + (Math.random() * (maxVal - minVal));

        return typeof floatVal == 'undefined' ? Math.round(randVal) : randVal.toFixed(floatVal);

    }
});
```

Does Anybody have idea about this ...

Comment: if two number's range is short, obviously number will get repeated.

Comment: You're going to have to keep track of which numbers have been picked already.  There's no other way to keep _random_ numbers from possibly repeating.  Or track down some kind of shuffle algorithm for your indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to maintain a list of numbers that have already been generated, and check against this list.  Re-generate a new number if you find a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the random numbers repeating themselves you have to keep track of the some way.

If you have the range you are dealing with is relatively small, you can create an array with all possible results and simply randomly pick out of it.

```
function Randomizer(minVal, maxVal, floatVal){
    var possible_results = []; // for larger arrays you can build this using a loop of course
    var randomization_array = [];
    var count = minVal;
    var incrementor = floatVal || 1; // set the distance between possible values (if floatVal equals 0 we round to 1)
    while (count <= maxVal) {
        possible_results.push(count);
        count += incrementor;
    }

    this.run = function(){
        // if randomization_array is empty set posssible results into it
        randomization_array = randomization_array.length ? randomization_array : $.merge(randomization_array, possible_results);
        // pick a random element within the array
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomization_array.length);
        // return the relevant element
        return randomization_array.splice(rand,1)[0];   
    }
}
```

and in order to use it (it creates a specialized object for each possible range):

```
rand = new Randomizer(1,10,0);
rand.run();
```

note that this approach does not work well for very large ranges